Microphones Not Detected on ThinkPad Running Windows 11 - Possible Driver Issue?
I have a ThinkPad X1 Carbon running Windows 11 Pro. I'm facing issues with the microphones built into my Sony WH-1000XM3 and Sony WF-1000XM4. Windows doesn't detect the microphones on either of these devices.
The microphones work fine with my mobile devices and on my wife's Inspiron 5593 running Windows 11 Home.
In my case, the "format" field is completely blank. On my wife's laptop, a format shows up and the microphones work perfectly. The main difference I noticed between the two laptops is the audio driver: mine is supplied by Intel, while hers is provided by Microsoft.


I'd really appreciate any suggestions on how to fix the microphone issue on my laptop.
P.S.: I also have an RHA MA650 and when connected, it uses the same Intel-provided driver and works fine.

The two pictures look identical to me. Is one supposed to be from the system with the driver supplied by Intel?

@ChesterGillon: Thanks for the heads up! I had uploaded the same image twice by mistake. I’ve now uploaded the correct screenshot.

Does clicking on the "Check for driver updates" link shown in the picture for your computer do anything?

@AndrewMorton: It directs me to the Windows Update section of the Settings app, which doesn’t find any driver updates.

@TuhinKarmakar Have you tried uninstalling the device(s) with the wrong driver? Then Windows might install the desired driver next time you plug in the headphones. Using Device Manager to Uninstall Devices and Driver Packages
